# Flutter position stack widget in center

Tags: dart, flutter

I have widgets in a stack so I'd like to position my button bar in the bottom center of the stack but nothing works. The widget just sticks to the left side. here is my code.

```
new Positioned(
            bottom: 40.0,
            child: new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: new ButtonBar(
                      alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new OutlineButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                new MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => new LoginPage()));
                          },
                          child: new Text(
                            "Login",
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                        new RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                new MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        new RegistrationPage()));
                          },
                          child: new Text(
                            "Register",
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

I have literally tried every center alignment, please help

Comment: did you try `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` on Column ? And by removing the `Align` widget

Comment: Yes i tried it @RémiRousselet ,  it still aligns to the left

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Remove everything, but this:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: new ButtonBar(
    alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      new OutlineButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => new LoginPage()));
        },
        child: new Text(
          "Login",
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      new RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                new RegistrationPage()));
        },
        child: new Text(
          "Register",
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

In my theory, the additional `Container` is destroying it. I would advise you to just surround this by adding `Padding`:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
  child: Align...
),
```

This seems a lot more reasonable to me than the `Positioned` and also I do not quite understand your `Column` with a single child only.

Comment: Woah, thanks man, I never knew Align can position widgets in a Stack to be honest

Answer (score 430):

You can use the `Positioned.fill` with `Align` inside a `Stack`:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[      
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: ....                
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes when calling Positioned.fill(), you are getting the full size (it will fill the view), then Align can do whatever it wants inside it. If you replaced the Align with a container with a red background, the stack would get all red.

Comment: i only used aligned and it did a job

Answer (score 389):

### Probably the most elegant way.

You can simply use the `alignment` option present in `Stack`

```
child: Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly and doesn't stretch the content as Positioned.fill do

Comment: But how to do it when you have more than one child on the Stack and you only want one of them to be in the center?

Answer (score 81):

For anyone who is reaching here and is not able to solve their issue, I used to make my widget horizontally center by setting both right and left to 0 like below:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      top: 100,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: Text("Search",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xff757575),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          fontFamily: "Roboto",
          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
          fontSize: 56.0,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
  ]
)
```

Comment: Can you explain why the left and right values were required?

Comment: A practice commonly used in Web. 

Comment: Now this is what I call a simple solution! Thanks mate

Comment: Nope.. it just makes it take up the entire width

Comment: This only works because of that textAlign: center. The widget is stretched edge to edge.

Answer (score 22):

Thanks to all of the above answers I'd like to share something that may come in handy in some certain cases. So lets see what happens when you use `Positioned:( right: 0.0, left:0.0, bottom:0.0)`  :

```
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
                bottom: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('Hello',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffF6C37F),
                          fontSize: 46, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                      )
                  ),
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

This would be the output of the above code:

[image]

As you can see it would fill the whole width with the container even though you don't want it and you just want the container to wrap its children. so for this you can try trick below:

```
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
                bottom: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                      child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Text('Hello',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffF6C37F), 
                            fontSize: 46, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(),
                  ],
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can change the Positioned with Align inside a Stack:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: ... ,
),
```

For more info about Stack: [Exploring Stack](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-stack-in-flutter-3264619b3a77)

Comment: the best solution so far, especially for positioning `Text`s. `Positioned` with `left:0` and `right:0` expands the actual widget horizontally.

Answer (score 11):

The Problem is the Container that gets the smallest possible size.

Just give a `width:` to the Container (in red) and you are done.

`width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`

[image]

```
  new Positioned(
  bottom: 0.0,
  child: new Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    color: Colors.red,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: new ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new OutlineButton(
                onPressed: null,
                child: new Text(
                  "Login",
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                onPressed: null,
                child: new Text(
                  "Register",
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Why don't you just use Columns / Rows here?

Comment: There are different solutions to achieve the expected result. My answer was trying to explain why the solution the OP provided did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this solution I came up with

`Positioned( child: SizedBox( child: CircularProgressIndicator(), width: 50, height: 50,), left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 25);`

Comment: This actually works in the case of using a relatively small widget, where you could set a fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

The Best way worked for me, was using `Align`.
I needed to make the profile picture of a user in the bottom center of the Cover picture.

```
return Container(
  height: 220,
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 160,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: UserProfileImage(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

this code does the trick

```
    Positioned(
                    bottom: 10,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                       
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

It can work like Positioned.center
You determine the center of the widget and set the same center of widget and point.

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class AlignPositioned extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const AlignPositioned({
    Key? key,
    this.alignment = Alignment.center,
    required this.centerPoint,
    this.widthFactor,
    this.heightFactor,
    Widget? child,
  })  : assert(widthFactor == null || widthFactor >= 0.0),
        assert(heightFactor == null || heightFactor >= 0.0),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  final AlignmentGeometry alignment;
  final Offset centerPoint;

  final double? widthFactor;

  final double? heightFactor;

  @override
  _RenderPositionedBox createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return _RenderPositionedBox(
      alignment: alignment,
      widthFactor: widthFactor,
      heightFactor: heightFactor,
      textDirection: Directionality.maybeOf(context),
      centerPoint: this.centerPoint,
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, _RenderPositionedBox renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..alignment = alignment
      ..widthFactor = widthFactor
      ..heightFactor = heightFactor
      ..textDirection = Directionality.maybeOf(context)
      ..centerPoint = centerPoint;
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties
        .add(DiagnosticsProperty<AlignmentGeometry>('alignment', alignment));
    properties
        .add(DoubleProperty('widthFactor', widthFactor, defaultValue: null));
    properties
        .add(DoubleProperty('heightFactor', heightFactor, defaultValue: null));
  }
}

class _RenderPositionedBox extends RenderAligningShiftedBox {
  Offset centerPoint;

  _RenderPositionedBox({
    RenderBox? child,
    double? widthFactor,
    double? heightFactor,
    AlignmentGeometry alignment = Alignment.center,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    required this.centerPoint,
  })  : assert(widthFactor == null || widthFactor >= 0.0),
        assert(heightFactor == null || heightFactor >= 0.0),
        _widthFactor = widthFactor,
        _heightFactor = heightFactor,
        super(child: child, alignment: alignment, textDirection: textDirection);

  double? get widthFactor => _widthFactor;
  double? _widthFactor;

  set widthFactor(double? value) {
    assert(value == null || value >= 0.0);
    if (_widthFactor == value) return;
    _widthFactor = value;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  set alignment(AlignmentGeometry value) {
    super.alignment = value;
    _resolvedAlignment = alignment.resolve(textDirection);
  }

  double? get heightFactor => _heightFactor;
  double? _heightFactor;
  late Alignment _resolvedAlignment = alignment.resolve(textDirection);

  set heightFactor(double? value) {
    assert(value == null || value >= 0.0);
    if (_heightFactor == value) return;
    _heightFactor = value;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  @override
  Size computeDryLayout(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    final bool shrinkWrapWidth =
        _widthFactor != null || constraints.maxWidth == double.infinity;
    final bool shrinkWrapHeight =
        _heightFactor != null || constraints.maxHeight == double.infinity;
    if (child != null) {
      final Size childSize = child!.getDryLayout(constraints.loosen());
      return constraints.constrain(Size(
        shrinkWrapWidth
            ? childSize.width * (_widthFactor ?? 1.0)
            : double.infinity,
        shrinkWrapHeight
            ? childSize.height * (_heightFactor ?? 1.0)
            : double.infinity,
      ));
    }
    return constraints.constrain(Size(
      shrinkWrapWidth ? 0.0 : double.infinity,
      shrinkWrapHeight ? 0.0 : double.infinity,
    ));
  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    final BoxConstraints constraints = this.constraints;
    final bool shrinkWrapWidth =
        _widthFactor != null || constraints.maxWidth == double.infinity;
    final bool shrinkWrapHeight =
        _heightFactor != null || constraints.maxHeight == double.infinity;

    if (child != null) {
      child!.layout(constraints.loosen(), parentUsesSize: true);
      size = constraints.constrain(Size(
        shrinkWrapWidth
            ? child!.size.width * (_widthFactor ?? 1.0)
            : double.infinity,
        shrinkWrapHeight
            ? child!.size.height * (_heightFactor ?? 1.0)
            : double.infinity,
      ));

      final BoxParentData childParentData = child!.parentData! as BoxParentData;
      final moveX = _resolvedAlignment.x - 1;
      final moveY = _resolvedAlignment.y - 1;
      log(_resolvedAlignment.y.toString());
      childParentData.offset = this.centerPoint +
          Offset(
            child!.size.width / 2 * moveX,
            child!.size.height / 2 * moveY,
          );
      // log(_resolvedAlignment.x.toString());
      // log(_resolvedAlignment.y.toString());

      // _resolvedAlignment.alongOffset(size - child!.size as Offset);
    } else {
      size = constraints.constrain(Size(
        shrinkWrapWidth ? 0.0 : double.infinity,
        shrinkWrapHeight ? 0.0 : double.infinity,
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  void debugPaintSize(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    super.debugPaintSize(context, offset);
    assert(() {
      final Paint paint;
      if (child != null && !child!.size.isEmpty) {
        final Path path;
        paint = Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeWidth = 1.0
          ..color = const Color(0xFFFFFF00);
        path = Path();
        final BoxParentData childParentData =
            child!.parentData! as BoxParentData;
        if (childParentData.offset.dy > 0.0) {
          // vertical alignment arrows
          final double headSize =
              math.min(childParentData.offset.dy * 0.2, 10.0);
          path
            ..moveTo(offset.dx + size.width / 2.0, offset.dy)
            ..relativeLineTo(0.0, childParentData.offset.dy - headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(headSize, 0.0)
            ..relativeLineTo(-headSize, headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(-headSize, -headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(headSize, 0.0)
            ..moveTo(offset.dx + size.width / 2.0, offset.dy + size.height)
            ..relativeLineTo(0.0, -childParentData.offset.dy + headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(headSize, 0.0)
            ..relativeLineTo(-headSize, -headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(-headSize, headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(headSize, 0.0);
          context.canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
        if (childParentData.offset.dx > 0.0) {
          // horizontal alignment arrows
          final double headSize =
              math.min(childParentData.offset.dx * 0.2, 10.0);
          path
            ..moveTo(offset.dx, offset.dy + size.height / 2.0)
            ..relativeLineTo(childParentData.offset.dx - headSize, 0.0)
            ..relativeLineTo(0.0, headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(headSize, -headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(-headSize, -headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(0.0, headSize)
            ..moveTo(offset.dx + size.width, offset.dy + size.height / 2.0)
            ..relativeLineTo(-childParentData.offset.dx + headSize, 0.0)
            ..relativeLineTo(0.0, headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(-headSize, -headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(headSize, -headSize)
            ..relativeLineTo(0.0, headSize);
          context.canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
      } else {
        paint = Paint()..color = const Color(0x90909090);
        context.canvas.drawRect(offset & size, paint);
      }
      return true;
    }());
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties
        .add(DoubleProperty('widthFactor', _widthFactor, ifNull: 'expand'));
    properties
        .add(DoubleProperty('heightFactor', _heightFactor, ifNull: 'expand'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

short solushion
put widget in Center() widget

Answer (score -2):

You can try this too:

```
Center(
  child: Stack(
    children: [],
  ),
)
```