# How to center a `Positioned` at a specific coordinate?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to use [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) to freely place widgets on a [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html). It looks like by default `Positioned` only offers to place its child using either `left`, `right`, `top`, or `bottom`. This has the behavior to align one of the boundaries to the given coordinate. What I'd like to achieve is to place the child at a certain `x`/`y` coordinate, but center it on it.

An example:

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Some App",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            child: SomeChild(text: "Some child"),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            child: Container(width: 5, height: 5, color: Colors.red.shade900),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 100,
            top: 150,
            child: SomeChild(text: "Some child with longer text"),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 100,
            top: 150,
            child: Container(width: 5, height: 5, color: Colors.red.shade900),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SomeChild extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  const SomeChild({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text);
  }
}
```

Results in:

[image]

[Example on Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=907c8dbc30331e2caf9d7a06d81392ba&null_safety=true)

Basically I'd like the children to center on the small debug gizmos.

Note: I'm using `SomeChild` as a placeholder for an arbitrary child whose size I neither know nor control explicitly.

Naive attempts at solving the problem where using a `Center` to wrap the child, but that has no effect. I also tried to move the `Positioned` into the children, doing some manual size determination within the children itself, so that they can shift their `top` and `right` coordiate by half their size. But that is not only awkward, and has to be implemented for every children manually, I also had problems making it work in the first place, because `Stack` complained that its children are no longer either a `Positioned`/`Aligned`/`Container`.

Is there an elegant way to center the child of a `Positioned` generically?

---

I think this question is different from [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819354/flutter-position-stack-widget-in-center), because there the goal is to center a child w.r.t. the `Stack` itself, not a certain coordinate.

Comment: `What I'd like to achieve is to place the child at a certain x/y coordinate, but center it on it.` what do you mean by center it on it? You mean the red dots will always be at the center of the `SomeChild` widget despite how long the words is going to be?

Comment: @TryHarder Yes exactly. For instance in the case `(100, 100)` I'd like the text to be centered on `(100, 100)`, not left/right/bottom/top aligned on it. Or speaking in terms of the 5x5 red boxes: I'd like them to be at `(97.5, 102.5)` instead of `(100, 105)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need [FractionalTranslation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionalTranslation-class.html)

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Some App",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            child: FractionalTranslation(
              translation: Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
              child: SomeChild(text: "Some child"),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            child: Container(width: 5, height: 5, color: Colors.red.shade900),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 100,
            top: 150,
            child: FractionalTranslation(
              translation: Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
              child: SomeChild(text: "Some child with longer text"),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 100,
            top: 150,
            child: Container(width: 5, height: 5, color: Colors.red.shade900),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SomeChild extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const SomeChild({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, that's what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the `left` or `x` value and `top` or `y` values by subtracting the `width` and `height` from the coordinates:

```dart
Size widgetSize = Size(200,100); // the size of the widget you want to position
Offset position = Offset(300,400); //the position of the widget on the screen
.
.
.
Positioned(
  left: position.dx - widgetSize.width/2,
  top: position.dy - widgetSize.height/2,
  child: ...
),
```

For this to work you predefine the child widget's size with the widgetSize.

Then you can put SomeChild inside a Container with that widgetSize and center it:

```dart
Positioned(
  left: position.dx - widgetSize.width/2,
  top: position.dy - widgetSize.height/2,
  child: Container(
    width: widgetSize.width,
    height: widgetSize.height,
    child: Center(
      child: SomeWidget(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Note that widgetSize should be greater than the size of someWidget.
You could make widgetSize gigantic in order to fit any someWidget.

Comment: While this is still helpful, the question was specifically for the case where I cannot hardcode the size of the children. As mentioned in the question: _I'm using `SomeChild` as a placeholder for an arbitrary child whose size I neither know nor control explicitly_. What if the child still exceeds the predefined size?

Comment: again you could make the size like 9999999x9999999 or whatever... it is not nice but should work. I don't think anything would and should exeed this size.

Answer (score 0):

May try this out. You can replace `Positioned.fill` with `Positioned` to suit your needs. Hope this help you out :D

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Some App",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
          // try replace Positioned.fill > Positioned
          Positioned.fill(
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(width: 5, height: 5, color: Colors.blue),
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child:  SomeChild(text: "THIS IS A VERY LONG LONG TEXT, NARUHODO!!!! KJASNDKJASNDAJKNSDKJANSJKNJKANDJS"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 100,
            top: 150,
            child: SomeChild(text: "Some child with longer text"),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 100,
            top: 150,
            child: Container(width: 5, height: 5, color: Colors.red.shade900),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But as far as I can see that only centers the debug gizmo w.r.t. the text. They are both still left aligned at `(100, 100)` and not centered on top of that coordinate. I'd like the center of an arbitrary child to be at a given `(x, y)`. Perhaps an example helps: Imagine a map application, where you know that a certain map feature is at `(x, y)`. Let's say we have multiple highlighter/marker widgets of unknown size (e.g. small circle, large circle, pulsating circle). The goal is to draw these highlighter widgets centered exactly at the given coordinate.

Answer (score -1):

Row and Column widgets has axis-alignment parameter.. you can easly center a view by using them

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Somehow I cannot get them to work with `Positioned` though, probably for the same reason `Center` doesn't work. At least (single or double) wrapping `SomeChild` with both `Row` and `Column` and setting `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` on both doesn't have an effect. Could you illustrate how you would adapt the code exactly?