# Flutter - AndroidStudio: how do i place an image under a container without expanding it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

i have a list using sticky headers. i want to place a custome made shadow under each header so i did the following:

```
return StickyHeader(
      header: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: AppColors.todaysTasks,
                height: 60.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: spacing),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  style: FontStyles.taskListItemName.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              Image.asset(
                'assets/images/BlurCropped.png',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      content: Column(
```

the problem is that my shadow expands the header's container and creates a large margin between each header and the first task. I've provided an image. please help me im lost here.

i was trying to put a shadow image under a header but it created a weird margin.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an image as a shadow, it is not laid over the content. Here are two solutions:

1. Using `decoration: BoxDecoration` for the container instead of the image (an example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52228086/13755145)
2. Or, if you want to keep using the image as a shadow, you could use a `Stack` in `content` and wrap the image with `Positioned`. (an example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57233221/13755145)

I would try to use the first approach, because positioning is not that easy.